# Detailed kinetic explanation for vapor pressure reduction by dissolved solute?

Tags: solutions, vapor-pressure, colligative-properties, evaporation

The following problem was asked in JEE Mains 2020 (Sept 2, Shift 1),

> An open beaker of water in equilibrium with water vapor is in a sealed container. When a few grams of glucose are added to the beaker of water, the rate at which water molecules:
>
> (A) leaves the solution increases
> (B) leaves the solution decreases
> (C) leaves the vapor increases
> (D) leaves the vapor decreases

According to the NCERT for Class XII, Part I, [pg. 46, para 3](https://ncert.nic.in/textbook.php?lech1=2-9),

> In  a  pure  liquid  the  entire  surface  is occupied by the molecules of the liquid. If anon-volatile solute is added to a solvent to give  a  solution  [Fig.  2.4.(b)],  the  vapor pressure  of  the  solution  is  solely  from  the solvent  alone.  This  vapor  pressure  of  the solution at a given temperature is found to be  lower  than  the  vapor  pressure  of  the pure  solvent  at  the  same  temperature.  In the solution, the surface has both solute and solvent molecules; thereby the fraction of the surface covered by the solvent molecules gets reduced.  Consequently,  the  number  of solvent molecules escaping from the surface is correspondingly reduced, thus, the vapor pressure is also reduced.

So, after reading the last lines of above quoted text, I think that the vapor pressure is reduced, because the rate at which solvent molecules leaves the solution decreases, due to a decrease in *exposed* surface area. So, acc. to me option (B) should be correct. But, it was incorrect, acc. to the key.

Is there anything else, I'm missing?

---

The answer given is,

> (C) leaves the vapor increases

Comment: It seems to me it is less about principles and more about the formulation of the task. In some ways both B and C are correct. B is correct as the rate of evaporation decreases. C is correct, as the net rate of the phase exchange increases in favor of vapour condensation. But I consider this interpretation as tricky, supporting B.

Comment: B is correct. So there is too much vapor the immediate rate does not change! as the partial pressure of water is lowered the rate of condensation lowers until it reaches the rate of evaporation in the new solution so D is also correct.

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to specifically commment on this:

According to the NCERT for Class XII, Part I, [pg. 46, para 3][1],

> In  a  pure  liquid  the  entire  surface  is occupied by the molecules of the liquid. If a non-volatile solute is added to a solvent to give  a  solution  [Fig.  2.4.(b)],  the  vapor pressure  of  the  solution  is  solely  from  the solvent  alone.  This  vapor  pressure  of  the solution at a given temperature is found to be  lower  than  the  vapor  pressure  of  the pure  solvent  at  the  same  temperature.  **In the solution, the surface has both solute and solvent molecules; thereby the fraction of the surface covered by the solvent molecules gets reduced.  Consequently,  the  number  of solvent molecules escaping from the surface is correspondingly reduced, thus, the vapor pressure is also reduced.**
> [emphasis mine]

NCERT's explanation for why vapor pressure is lowered due to the presence of a dissolved solute is incorrect, because **vapor pressure is independent of the surface area accesible to the solvent** (assuming it's non-zero).  Consider these two examples:

1. You have two sealed containers, both of which contain an open beaker of identical solvent.  In container A, the beaker is low and wide.  In container B, the beaker is tall and narrow.  The surface area of solvent in container B is thus smaller.  Yet, assuming the conditions in the respective containers are identical, the equilibrium vapor pressures will be the same.
2. You have two sealed containers, both of which contain an open beaker of identical solvent.  The beakers are identical, so the surface area of liquid is the same. The conditions in the containers are also identical.  Glucose is dissolved into the solvent in container A, while sucrose is dissolved into the solvent in container B.  The final concentrations are the same.  Sucrose is larger than glucose.  Consequently, the fraction of the surface area covered by solvent in container A is larger than in container B.  Yet, ignoring non-ideality, the vapor pressures are the same; they depend only on the concentration of solute, not its nature.

The surface area only matters for kinetics, i.e., for how quickly the solvent can escape the container to reach equilibrium.  Clearly, with a larger surface area, the equilibrium vapor pressure will be reached more rapidly.

Feel free to send an email to NCERT with a link to this comment.

Here's the thermodynamic explanation: The addition of solute lowers the chemical potential of the solvent, due to the entropy of mixing.  [There can also be energetic effects, in either direction, but with a soluble solute the entropy term is dominant.]

At equilibrium, the chemical potential of the solvent in the liquid and vapor phases must be equal.  Thus, since the chemical potential of the solvent in the liquid phase has lowered, that of the the solvent in the vapor phase must lower as well.

And since the chemical potential of a gas increases with its partial pressure, the vapor pressure of the solvent in the gas phase will decrease until its chemical potential reaches the new (lowered) chemical potential of the solvent in the liquid phase.

As far as the question itself goes, I'm uncertain, because the question is asking for a kinetic, rather than a thermodynamic, explanation.  But I can offer two alternative pictures:

Let's represent the movement between the liquid and vapor phases of the solvent ("X"), as follows:

$$\ce{X_{(l)}<=>X_{(g)}}$$

Picture (I): Both "B" and "C" are correct.

Let's start with the vapor in equilibrium with pure solvent.  At equilibrium, the rates of the forward and backward reactions are equal.

Now suppose we add solute to the liquid phase.  This shifts the reaction to the left, which means that the rate of the forward reaction initially decreases (which is answer "B") and the rate of the backward reaction initially increases (which is answer "C").  Eventually the system reaches its new equilibrium point, at which point the rates of the forward and reverse reactions are again equal.

Picture (II): "B" is correct.

Again, let's start with the vapor in equilibrium with pure solvent.  At equilibrium, the rates of the forward and backward reactions are equal.

Now suppose we add solute to the liquid phase. The rate at which gas enters the liquid phase depends only on the concentration of gas, so the backwards reaction will be unaffected by the presence of the solute in the liquid.  However, the rate of the forward reaction will be reduced, since it is now more favorable to for the solvent to remain in the liquid state.  Hence the answer is "B".

As I mention in the Comments:

In Picture (I), the change in relative chemical potentials would raise the energetic barrier in the forward direction and lower it in the reverse direction, which would in turn increase the % of collisions that are succesful in the rev. direction, thus increasing the rate of the rev. reaction even though the collision frequency of the vapor with the liquid woudn't be changed by the presence of the dissolved solute.

But: If there isn't any barrier in the rev. direction, such that 100% of vapor molecules that collide with the liquid phase become liquid, then Picture (I) would not apply.

I'm afraid I don't know enough about the microscopic kinetics to have certainty on this.  Perhaps someone that has done simulation work on this could provide an answer.  [But to get this, you would want to vote to reopen the question.]

Comment: If I've understood you clearly, then you're saying that my answer seems reasonable, as decrease in exposed SA takes it longer to reach the equilibrium vapor pressure. But, the reduction in vapor pressure isn't a consequence of decrease in exposed SA. Am I right?

Comment: NCERT's explanation is supported [here](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/boundless-chemistry/chapter/colligative-properties-of-nonelectrolyte-solutions/#:~:text=A%20solvent's%20vapor%20pressure%20will,electrolytic%20and%20non%2Delectrolytic%20solutions) and [here](https://www.chem.purdue.edu/gchelp/solutions/colligv.html). I can't think of a way to refute your explantion. What do *you* think is the reason for lowering of vappour pressure?

Comment: @RobinSingh  See the explanation I added.  BTW, this is not *my* explanation, this is the standard thermodynamic explanation.

Comment: @RahulVerma  Your second sentence is correct.  You can read what I added to the end of my answer.

Comment: This doesn't sound right: "the rate of the backward reaction initially increases". Following your own logic there is no reason why the rate of collision of the gas molecules with the surface of the solution should increase simply because something was added to the solution.

Comment: @BuckThorn  Yeah, I was wondering along those same lines, which is why I doubly-qualified my answer with "...unless I'm missing something subtle about the kinetics..." and "...I believe..."  But then I thought in terms of a simple kinetic model, where the rate of reaction is proportional to the rate of collisions times the percent of those that are sucessful. Given this, my picture was that the change in relative chemical potentials would raise the energetic barrier in the forward direction and lower it in the reverse direction, which would in turn increase the % of collisions that are....

Comment: ....succesful in the rev. direction, thus increasing the rate of the rev. reaction even though the collision frequency of the vapor with the liquid woudn't be changed by the presence of the dissolved solute. But: If there isn't any barrier in the rev. direction, such that 100% of vapor molecules that collide with the liquid phase become liquid, then my thinking wouldn't apply. But, again, I don't know enough about the kinetics to have a solid picture on this, hence the explicit uncertainty with which I characterized the "answer" part of my post (that's also why I placed it at the end).

Comment: I just edited my answer to mention both of these pictures.

Answer (score 0):

Water is in equilibrium with vapor. The simple interpretation is that rates of condensation and evaporation are equal, but that is not really true in the description of an open beaker in a closed space with respect to the beaker eventually the liquid would be dispersed thruout the container droplets here, there, and everywhere. Addition of a solute to the liquid definitely lowers the vapor pressure of that liquid . It does NOTHING to the vapor at the moment of dissolution. A simple experiment to show this would be to have two identical beakers in the enclosed space one with pure water the other with the solution; a careful observation will show that water will leave the pure water and accumulate in the solution. the rate of condensation is not affected by the solution. It is affected by the partial pressure of the water vapor in the container.

If the only source of water vapor is the beaker with the solute[!] the rate of evaporation will decrease; the initial rate of condensation will be the same and the partial pressure of water vapor will then slowly decrease and the rate of condensation will slowly decrease until equilibrium at the new vapor pressure is established. The question is simply inane.

Answer (score -1):

I am also a JEE Aspirant and this question intrigued me. This is also my first answer on Stack Exchange :)

First of all we need to understand that Vapour Pressure decreases when any solute is added to a solvent, i.e $$VP_solution < VP_solvent$$
A very simple explanation for this is that the solute particles introduce new forces of attraction between themselves and solvent molecules and these forces help to prevent vaporisation of solvent.

Another thing to know that Vapour Pressure is an **equilibrium** phenomenon. In the question as soon as the glucose is added, the already existing equilibrium was disturbed.

There was already an equilibrium stage attained where as many molecules were leaving the solution, were also leaving the vapour state.

Now the addition of glucose has lowered the amount of molecules leaving the solution. So when the new equilibrium is attained, the Vapour Pressure will be less than what it was when no glucose was added.

Now it is understood that Vapour Pressure must decrease, i.e, more molecules should leave the vapour state. Just lowering the **amount** of molecules leaving the solution wouldn't decrease the Vapour Pressure. So, the rate at which the molecules leave the vapour must increase and this is why Vapour Pressure decreases.

Mind you, when the new equilibrium is attained the amount and rate of molecules leaving and entering the solution become equal but they are less than what they were initially.

I hope this helped!

Comment: If you remove vapor the rate of removal must slow;  as you state in your penultimate paragraph. [thanks for the chance to use that word]

Comment: Please can someone provide constructive criticism on why my answer was downvoted?

Comment: Because your explanation was not correct. You explain it yourself in the next to last paragraph. At equilibrium the rates are equal if the forward reaction is slower the reverse reaction must also be slower. The condensation reaction monotonically slows.

Comment: @jimchmst I see. Thanks for clarifying it! I'll try to understand this better :)

Comment: Guri It took me years and I have a long way to go. the best way is to assume equilibrium then study carefully what happens if it is perturbed by various methods. In this case the sticky sugar solution is similar to the vacuum sucking mechanism.